# UK ISO mechanical keyboard layout on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu 14.04 to use with the keyboard layout shown here 
[UK Keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#mediaviewer/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg). I can't find any options from the list of English (UK) keyboard layouts that match this format, despite it being common in the UK. A similar question was posted [on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1641742&s=f707bb8610df0d5584ef359c7b4bede8) but it seems that the UK-ISO format may have been dropped. If that's the case, can alternative layouts be added through some other means?